# Facebook FQL - A user access token is required to request this resource

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-fql

I've been having a problem with a specific FQL call for a few days now, hoping someone can point me in the right direction, and yes, correct permissions are being asked for.

Using the PHP SDK, making the following FQL multiquery works

```
$user_fql = urlencode("SELECT uid, first_name, middle_name, last_name, name, birthday_date, hometown_location, current_location, education, religion, political, interests, work FROM user WHERE uid = me()");
$friend_count_fql = urlencode("SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = me()");
$multiquery = json_encode(array("user" => $user_fql, "friend_count" => $friend_count_fql));
$user = $facebook->api("/fql?q=".$multiquery."&access_token=".$access_token."&format=json-strings");
```

However when making this FQL call

```
$friends_fql = urlencode("SELECT uid, first_name, middle_name, last_name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) LIMIT 10");
$friends = $facebook->api("/fql?q=".$friends_fql."&access_token=".$access_token."&format=json-strings");
```

The following error is thrown

```
{"error":{"message":"A user access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":102}}
```

And the permissions we are asking for

```
create_note email, friends_birthday, friends_education_history, friends_groups 
friends_hometown, friends_interests, friends_likes, friends_location, 
friends_relationships, friends_religion_politics, friends_work_history, photo_upload, 
publish_actions, publish_stream, read_stream share_item status_update user_birthday 
user_education_history, user_hometown, user_likes user_location, user_religion_politics, 
user_work_history, video_upload
```

I can't figure why getting user's friends info is throwing an OAuthException since this was working locally before pushing it to a  remote server and the user access token I'm testing with is valid for the app and hasn't expired.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using your uid instead of me() because I'm guessing that when you left your local environment facebook isn't grabbing the me() correctly.

I just tried your call on my graph api explorer and didn't get any problems and since you're not getting a permissions error it must be facebook doesn't know who "me()" is.

Double check that you are logged onto facebook in the environment your working on/ try running the call with your uid.